# Dynamically coloring a terrain surface based on extent/visible elevation

Tags: symbology, bathymetry, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

This application is being developed using ArcGIS JS.

I have a 3d rendered terrain surface of the ocean floor. I've created a raster file to represent this 3d surface, created a tile-cache from said raster, and exposed that tile-cache as a rest service. This means that I can pass the 3d rendered surface of the ocean floor (as an elevation layer) to ArcGIS JS to create a 3d terrain that can be flown over by the camera. Very cool.

The issue I now face is one of coloration. Without intelligent coloration of the 3d surface, everything is one color, and the shadowing effect of ArcGIS JS library can't reveal the level of detail I want. So, I created a colorized version of the raster, exposed this as an ImageLayer, and draped it on top of the elevation layer. All in all, I'm pretty happy with it.

My problem is this: The color ramp that I've selected is the largest available. Unfortunately, the range in elevation is so large that when you zoom into the terrain to see detail, you quickly descend into a tiny portion of the color ramp where everything looks the same. Even though you may be looking at a seamount that is in fact several hundred meters high, the top and the bottom are the same color because it's being squashed into the same color ramp as the entire range of elevation on the whole map.

My question is this: Is there a way for me to dynamically re-render/re-symbolize the color layer (it is currently an imagery layer, but it doesn't have to be. I can make it something else if that would help) so that the color ramp is fit to the elevations that are currently visible? For example, if from where the camera is positioned the highest visible elvation is say 100m of depth, and the lowest elevation is 500m of depth, can I re-render/re-symbolize the colors so that the color ramp is only stretched between 100-500m of depth? As opposed to the color ramp being statically fixed across the entire range of elevations on the entire map, regardless of what is in view. This would provide much more differentiation between elevations at both large ranges of elevation and narrow ranges of elevation.

I realize that I may not have worded that as clearly as I could have, but I can't think of a more eloquent way to explain it, so please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: This seems like an interesting question. Perhaps post some images of how it should ideally look when you zoom in.